# Is it possible to re-use deliberately left open sockets?

Tags: php, linux, sockets, tcp, file-descriptor

I'm using the [PHP sockets extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) (basically a wrapper around the `socket(2)`-related linux syscalls) and would like to re-use sockets I open while serving one request in the subsequent ones. Performance is a critical factor.

The sockets I open are all to the same IP, which makes the use of other functions like `pfsockopen()` impossible (because it reuses same single socket every time) and I need several at a time.

**The question**

If I leave the sockets I open serving one request deliberately open, (I don't call `socket_close()` or `socket_shutdown()`) and connect a socket with the exact same parameters to the same IP serving the next request; will linux re-use the previously opened socket / file-descriptor?

What I want to do in the end is to avoid TCP-handshakes on every request.

**Additional information**:

- I use the apache worker MPM - which means that different request *can be* but are not necessarily served from different processes. For the sake of simplicity let's assume that all requests are served from the same process.
- I can get the file-descriptor ID of a open and connected socket in PHP. I can open and read and write to `/dev/fd/{$id}`, yet to no purpose - it's not communicating with the remote server (maybe this is a naïve approach). If anybody knew how to make this work I'd consider that to be an acceptable answer too.

Comment: Just the little I know about the low level systems side of it, I believe a Linux system will try to use different file descriptors each time rather than recycling old ones.  Such as in your case it will most likely assign a new file descriptor for each socket that you use.  Also, you might run out of available file descriptors if you do not close them.  But I think you already knew that.

Comment: Kernel will re-use previously closed file descriptors for a process, but not open sockets. Do you have a way to keep state from one HTTP request to the next?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @NikolaiNFetissov: Yes I do, but PHP does not expose raw file-descriptors, and I can't really save a PHP socket resource anywhere (I assume they're not serializable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer given by [Jirka Hanika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235565/jirka-hanika) is correct for most systems, I have come to the conclusion that it regretfully does not apply to PHP; the re-use of sockets using the PHP [sockets extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) is impossible to achieve from user space.

The code that led to this conclusion is:

```
function statDescriptors() {
    foreach (glob('/proc/self/fd/*') as $sFile) {
        $r = realpath($sFile);
        // ignore local file descriptors
        if($r === false) {
            echo `stat {$sFile}`, "\n";
        }
    }       
}

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

statDescriptors();

$oSocket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

socket_set_option($oSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 1);
socket_set_option($oSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

socket_connect($oSocket, '173.194.35.33', 80); // Google IP

socket_write($oSocket, 'GET / HTTP/1.0' . "\r\n");
socket_write($oSocket, 'Connection: Keep-Alive' . "\r\n\r\n");

socket_read($oSocket, 1024 * 8);

// socket_close($oSocket); // toggle this line comment during test

echo 'PID is: ', getmypid(), "\n";

statDescriptors();
```

This code will `stat()` the current process' open socket file descriptors at the start and end of its' execution. In between it will open a socket with `SO_KEEPALIVE` set, write a request to it and read a response. Then it will optionally close the socket (toggle line comment) and echo the current process' PID (to make sure you're in the same process).

You will see that regardless if you close the socket or not, the file descriptor created serving the previous request will not exist anymore at the beginning of this cycle's execution and a completely new socket will be created and connected.

I was unable to test `SOCK_CLOEXEC` since it's not (yet?) implemented in the extension.

(This was tested using PHP 5.4.0)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reuse the socket in the same process, simply leave the connection open.  That is actually your only option of avoiding TCP handshakes.  Make sure keepalives are on:

```
s.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
```

If you want to spawn new processes and pass the connection to them, yes, they will be able to write to `/dev/fd/{$id}` and this will send the data over network.  Just make sure that the sockets are not closed during exec (learn about `SOCK_CLOEXEC`).

Passing the socket to an unrelated process is not possible.  You would have to use some form of interprocess communication to accomplish that, and I am not sure that the overhead of TCP handshake in intranet or internet conditions would be enough to justify the complexity and other overhead associated with that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe that `SO_KEEPALIVE` applies only to listening sockets, not peer sockets. Yet I didn't specify that explicitly in my question either. So thumbs up!

Comment: @Tom - Thanks too.  You can use `SO_KEEPALIVE` on client side; before connecting or even after the connection is established (just not in the middle of the handshake).

Answer (score 0):

> If I leave the sockets I open serving one request deliberately open,
>   (I don't call socket_close() or socket_shutdown()) and connect a
>   socket with the exact same parameters to the same IP serving the next
>   request; will linux re-use the previously opened socket /
>   file-descriptor?

No, but you could always keep using the original one, if you are in the same process. What you are talking about is really connection pooling.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Remember that PHP is stateless and there's no direct way of passing on resources from one request-cycle to the next.